# I have a Spanned text with some formatting. How do I convert it into a String based on that formatting?

Tags: java, android, string, spanned

```
Spanned spanned = article.getArticleBody();
TextView body =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.article_body);
```

How do I print this in body `TextView`

Comment: String htmlString = Html.toHtml(spannedText);

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Spanned spanned = article.getArticleBody(); 
body.setText(Html.toHtml(spannedText));
```

or this

```
 body.setText(spannedText);
```